# Mate in 4. Difficult. Going crazy

Tags: checkmate

A friend sent me this puzzle. He insists that Black has a mate in 4. I just can't find it.

[image]

Can someone see a mate in 4 moves here?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if the black king is in rank 1, but if it is, here's the mate in 4:

```
[FEN "R5R1/6PK/1N1r2PP/2QB1p2/8/p1np1r2/1ppq4/1k6 b - - 0 1"]

1... Qxh6+ 2. Kxh6 c1=Q+ 3. Qe3 (3. Kh7 Rh3#) 3... Qxe3+ 4. Kh7 Rh3#
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Indeed. Black is going down and white up

Comment: Solution looks bugged, there is no c1=Q+.

Comment: The answer is for the time that the black king is in line 1. @Allure

Comment: And also, I think there is no mate if the black king is in line 8. @Allure

Comment: @ImanMohammadi The usual word in English is "rank", not "line" - it took me a few minutes to understand what you mean, essentially that the trick here is the board is the opposite way around to what I think most chess players would intuitively expect.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited. @IanBush

Comment: White also has the option of Kh5 at moves 3 and 4, with the same result.